# Converting .pb to coreml

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo, coreml

I'm new to coreml and I'm trying to convert my tiny-yolov3 model to a coreml model, but I keep getting this error.

```
[SSAConverter] [78/170] Converting op type: 'Conv2D', name: 'yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/Conv2D', output_shape: (-1, 16, 416, 416).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanyang/Desktop/DW2TF/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/tensorflow/_tf_converter.py", line 95, in convert
    optional_inputs=optional_inputs)
  File "/Users/ryanyang/Desktop/DW2TF/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/nnssa/coreml/ssa_converter.py", line 149, in ssa_convert
    converter.convert()
  File "/Users/ryanyang/Desktop/DW2TF/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/nnssa/coreml/ssa_converter.py", line 567, in convert
    convert_func(node)
  File "/Users/ryanyang/Desktop/DW2TF/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/nnssa/coreml/ssa_converter.py", line 1493, in _convert_conv2d
    '[SSAConverter] Dynamic weights in convolution not implemented')
NotImplementedError: [SSAConverter] Dynamic weights in convolution not implemented
```

UPDATE: I have added minimum_ios_deployment_target="13" to the converter, but now it is giving me a different error.

My code is

```
import tfcoreml as tf_converter
tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path = 'data/yolov3-tiny-one-class.pb',
                     mlmodel_path = 'TinyYOLO.mlmodel',
                     output_feature_names = ['yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/BiasAdd'],
                     input_name_shape_dict = {'yolov3-tiny/net1' : [1, 416, 416, 3]},
                     image_input_names = ['yolov3-tiny/net1'],
                     image_scale = 1 / 255.0,
                     minimum_ios_deployment_target="13"
                     )
```

and my visualizer for my pb model from tf-coreml is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/net1, op type = ( Placeholder ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/net1:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/net1:0 : (?, 416, 416, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0 : (4,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0 : ()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max:0 : ()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform, op type = ( RandomUniform ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0 : (4,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform:0 : (3, 3, 3, 16)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

......
......

358: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/dilation_rate, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/dilation_rate:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/dilation_rate:0 : (2,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
359: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Conv2D, op type = ( Conv2D ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/route2:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/kernel/read:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Conv2D:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/route2:0 : (?, 26, 26, 384)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/kernel/read:0 : (3, 3, 384, 256)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Conv2D:0 : (?, 26, 26, 256)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
360: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Initializer/ones, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Initializer/ones:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Initializer/ones:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
361: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma, op type = ( VariableV2 ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
362: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Assign, op type = ( Assign ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Initializer/ones:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Assign:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma:0 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Initializer/ones:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/Assign:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
363: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/read, op type = ( Identity ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/read:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/read:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
364: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Initializer/zeros, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Initializer/zeros:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Initializer/zeros:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
365: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta, op type = ( VariableV2 ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
366: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Assign, op type = ( Assign ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Initializer/zeros:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Assign:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta:0 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Initializer/zeros:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/Assign:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
367: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/read, op type = ( Identity ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/read:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/read:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
368: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Initializer/zeros, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Initializer/zeros:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Initializer/zeros:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
369: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean, op type = ( VariableV2 ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
370: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Assign, op type = ( Assign ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Initializer/zeros:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Assign:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Initializer/zeros:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Assign:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
371: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/read, op type = ( Identity ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/read:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/read:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
372: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Initializer/ones, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Initializer/ones:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Initializer/ones:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
373: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance, op type = ( VariableV2 ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
374: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Assign, op type = ( Assign ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Initializer/ones:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Assign:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Initializer/ones:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Assign:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
375: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read, op type = ( Identity ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read:0 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
376: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm, op type = ( FusedBatchNorm ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Conv2D:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/read:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/read:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/read:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:1, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:2, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:3, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:4
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Conv2D:0 : (?, 26, 26, 256)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/gamma/read:0 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/beta/read:0 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_mean/read:0 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read:0 : (256,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:0 : (?, 26, 26, 256)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:1 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:2 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:3 : (256,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:4 : (256,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
377: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/Const, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/Const:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/Const:0 : ()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
378: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Activation, op type = ( LeakyRelu ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Activation:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:0 : (?, 26, 26, 256)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Activation:0 : (?, 26, 26, 256)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
379: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0 : (4,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
380: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0 : ()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
381: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max:0 : ()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
382: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform, op type = ( RandomUniform ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape:0 : (4,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
383: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub, op type = ( Sub ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max:0 : ()
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0 : ()
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub:0 : ()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
384: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul, op type = ( Mul ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub:0 : ()
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
385: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform, op type = ( Add ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min:0 : ()
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
386: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel, op type = ( VariableV2 ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
387: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Assign, op type = ( Assign ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Assign:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/Assign:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
388: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/read, op type = ( Identity ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/read:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/read:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
389: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Initializer/zeros, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Initializer/zeros:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Initializer/zeros:0 : (18,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
390: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias, op type = ( VariableV2 ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias:0 : (18,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
391: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Assign, op type = ( Assign ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Initializer/zeros:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Assign:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias:0 : (18,)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Initializer/zeros:0 : (18,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/Assign:0 : (18,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
392: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/read, op type = ( Identity ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/read:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias:0 : (18,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/read:0 : (18,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
393: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/dilation_rate, op type = ( Const ), inputs = , outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/dilation_rate:0
@input shapes:
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/dilation_rate:0 : (2,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
394: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/Conv2D, op type = ( Conv2D ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Activation:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/read:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/Conv2D:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional12/Activation:0 : (?, 26, 26, 256)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/kernel/read:0 : (1, 1, 256, 18)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/Conv2D:0 : (?, 26, 26, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
395: op name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/BiasAdd, op type = ( BiasAdd ), inputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/Conv2D:0, import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/read:0, outputs = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/BiasAdd:0
@input shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/Conv2D:0 : (?, 26, 26, 18)
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/bias/read:0 : (18,)
@output shapes:
name = import/yolov3-tiny/convolutional13/BiasAdd:0 : (?, 26, 26, 18)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPS counts:
Placeholder : 1
ResizeNearestNeighbor : 1
ConcatV2 : 1
BiasAdd : 2
Fill : 4
MaxPool : 6
FusedBatchNorm : 11
LeakyRelu : 11
RandomUniform : 13
Sub : 13
Mul : 13
Add : 13
Conv2D : 13
VariableV2 : 59
Assign : 59
Identity : 60
Const : 116
```

Any help would be Greatly Appreciated !!!

Comment: Try adding the argument `minimum_ios_deployment_target="13"` to the call to `convert()`.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans, Hmm, it's now giving me a different error. 

packages/coremltools/converters/tensorflow/_tf_converter.py", line 99, in convert
    raise RuntimeError('failed to convert from IR to Core ML. {}'.format(e))
RuntimeError: failed to convert from IR to Core ML. [SSAConverter] Dynamic weights in convolution not implemented

Comment: I have no experience with the TF version of YOLOv3 but it sounds like it does things that Core ML does not support.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans do you recommend any other ways of converting tinyYOLOv3 to coreML?

Comment: The issue might be that one of your convolution layers does not have any weights (or it has more than two inputs). You might want to look into that. Also, did you try to freeze the TF graph before you did the Core ML conversion?

Comment: Oh, hmm, let me try that. If freezing the TF graph automatically saves it in .pb format, I can just use that to convert rather than trying to convert the weights to .pb format first.